# Work around for live filtering 1500+ items with jQuery in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, google-chrome, webkit

I'm being bitten by the Chrome/Webkit [71305](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71305) bug where un-hiding a large number of nodes causes Chrome to hang. (Also occurs in Safari).

I am filtering a list item that will be in a drop down menu with the following:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
    return $.trim((a.textContent || a.innerText || "")).toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) == 0;
};

var input = $('input');
var container = $('ul');

input.keyup(function(e) {
    var filter = $.trim(input.val());

    if (filter.length > 0) {
        // Show matches.
        container.find("li:Contains(" + filter + ")").css("display", "block");
        container.find("li:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").css("display", "none");
    }
    else {
        container.find('li').css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Snippet of the markup:

```
<input type="text" />
<ul>  
    <li>
        <div>
            <span title="93252"><label><input type="checkbox">3G</label></span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The time it takes for the Javascript to execute is negligible. It's when Chrome needs to redraw the elements after deleting the text in the `input` that it hangs. Does not happen in FF6/IE7-9.

I made a JSFiddle to illustrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/uUk7S/17/show/

Is there another approach I can take rather than hiding and showing the elements that will not cause Chrome to hang? I have tried cloning the `ul`, processing in the clone and replacing the `ul` in the DOM completely with the clone, but am hoping there's a better way as this is significantly slower in IE.

Comment: you are missing the closing bracket for the `span` elements. could that be the cause?

Comment: @William, that's just a mistake I made when cleaning up the markup in Vim. I'll fix the fiddle but the issue will still persist. (Especially since it works fine in the other browsers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried other css possibility for hiding the elements?

Using css props like  a switch of `visibility`? 
Or a switch between `height:auto` and `height:0;overflow-y:hidden;`?

I made a little example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8DUv/), it's using `.css({"visibility":"visible","height":"auto"});` to show and `({"visibility":"hidden","height":"0"})` to hide. And it seems to work fine in chrome in the few test I did.

**EDIT:** Even better [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8DUv/2/) , you just have to use `.css("visibility","visible");` and `.css("visibility","hidden");`. The use of `li[style~="hidden;"]{height:0;}` is doing the height modification for you.

Comment: The height change is the approach I was about to post.  Worked fine for me also.

Comment: This works well! Should note that if there is any `padding` added to the filtered elements, that also needs to be set to `0` in the style.

Answer (score -1):

Actualy, you can put empty value to `<li>` element. That actualy is only fix i was able to work. And when you need value again, put it back. Or you can remove `<li>`. But I more prefere for that, to use AJAX.